# How to add the displayed card back into the stack on swipe Right gesture in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-cardview

So, I am displaying the saved cards overlapped on each other and I am using Swipe Left gesture to remove that card from all the displayed cards. I want to add the card back again to the list of all displayed overlapped cards on doing Swipe gesture Right.The code I have implemented for Swipe.RIGHT gesture crashes the app when Swipe RIGHT. Below is my code that I have written written for Swipe

```
  val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object :ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT or ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT
        ){
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                val cardPair = adapter.currentList[position]

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                    // Handle swipe right to keep the card back in the stack

                    val newPosition = position - 1
                    if (newPosition >= 0 && position != newPosition) {
                        // Check if the card is not already in the desired position

                        adapter.currentList.removeAt(position)
                        adapter.currentList.add(newPosition, cardPair)
                        adapter.notifyItemMoved(position, newPosition)
                    }
                } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                    // Handle swipe left to delete the card
                    cardViewmodel.deleteCards(cardPair)
                }
            }





        })
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.recyclerview)
```

Logacat shows following error .

```
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~SErU_BmnDMbyfzEQeecmFw==/com.example.visuallithuanian-XnOaU6ybpinVUBBbfLO4wg==/base.apk': I/O error
2023-07-04 20:29:07.047   735-735   ResourcesManager        com.android.systemui                 E  failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~SErU_BmnDMbyfzEQeecmFw==/com.example.visuallithuanian-XnOaU6ybpinVUBBbfLO4wg==/base.apk'
                                                                                                    java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~SErU_BmnDMbyfzEQeecmFw==/com.example.visuallithuanian-XnOaU6ybpinVUBBbfLO4wg==/base.apk
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:295)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:144)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:454)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager.access$000(ResourcesManager.java:72)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:168)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:530)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:612)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:664)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1011)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1114)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2415)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1751)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1737)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1506)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3029)
                                                                                                        at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnbadgedIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:290)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.getBadgedIcon(SystemUIToast.java:286)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.inflateToastView(SystemUIToast.java:198)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.<init>(SystemUIToast.java:90)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.SystemUIToast.<init>(SystemUIToast.java:77)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastFactory.createToast(ToastFactory.java:78)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.lambda$showToast$0(ToastUI.java:113)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.$r8$lambda$w_gPCh3F8Xxn1jN4lkQZoUci71c(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:16)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.toast.ToastUI.showToast(ToastUI.java:140)
                                                                                                        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:1451)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```